# Apache flink Wikipedia edit analytics with Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to rewrite the wikipedia edit stream analytics in Apache Flink tutorials to Scala from https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/quickstart/run_example_quickstart.html

The code from the tutorial is

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FoldFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.KeyedStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.wikiedits.WikipediaEditEvent;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.wikiedits.WikipediaEditsSource;

public class WikipediaAnalysis {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    DataStream<WikipediaEditEvent> edits = see.addSource(new WikipediaEditsSource());

    KeyedStream<WikipediaEditEvent, String> keyedEdits = edits
      .keyBy(new KeySelector<WikipediaEditEvent, String>() {
        @Override
        public String getKey(WikipediaEditEvent event) {
          return event.getUser();
        }
      });

    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Long>> result = keyedEdits
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
      .fold(new Tuple2<>("", 0L), new FoldFunction<WikipediaEditEvent, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Long> fold(Tuple2<String, Long> acc, WikipediaEditEvent event) {
          acc.f0 = event.getUser();
          acc.f1 += event.getByteDiff();
          return acc;
        }
      });

    result.print();

    see.execute();
  }
}
```

below is my attempt in scala

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.wikiedits.{WikipediaEditEvent, WikipediaEditsSource}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time


object WikipediaAnalytics extends App{

  val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

  val edits = env.addSource(new WikipediaEditsSource());

  val keyedEdits = edits.keyBy(event => event.getUser)

  val result = keyedEdits.timeWindow(Time.seconds(5)).fold(("", 0L), (we: WikipediaEditEvent, t: (String, Long)) =>
    (we.getUser, t._2 + we.getByteDiff))

}
```

which is more or less a word to word conversion to scala, based on which the type of the `val result` should be `DataStream[(String, Long)]` but the actual type inferred after `fold()` is no where close.

Please help identify what is wrong with the scala code

***EDIT1***: made the below changes, using the currying schematic of `fold[R]` and the type now confirms to the expected type, but still couldn't get hold of the reason though

```
  val result_1: (((String, Long), WikipediaEditEvent) => (String, Long)) => DataStream[(String, Long)] =
    keyedEdits.timeWindow(Time.seconds(5)).fold(("", 0L))

  val result_2: DataStream[(String, Long)] = result_1((t: (String, Long), we: WikipediaEditEvent ) =>
    (we.getUser, t._2 + we.getByteDiff))
```

Comment: I think if there are many possibilities to resolve the final type, you would have to give type inference system a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the fold, you have to have a closing bracket after your accumulator initialValue. When you fix that, the code will fail to compile because it doesn't have TypeInformation available for WikipediaEditEvent. The easiest way to resolve that is to import more of flink scala API. See below for a full example:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.wikiedits.WikipediaEditsSource
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time

object WikipediaAnalytics extends App {
  val see: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  val edits = see.addSource(new WikipediaEditsSource())
  val userEditsVolume: DataStream[(String, Int)] = edits
    .keyBy(_.getUser)
    .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
    .fold(("", 0))((acc, event) => (event.getUser, acc._2 + event.getByteDiff))
  userEditsVolume.print()
  see.execute("Wikipedia User Edit Volume")
}
```